# Wrong output escaping in Symfony URL

Tags: php, symfony1, escaping

I'm trying to use url_for() helper function of Symfony to get some URL's for my web application.

url_for() function works well if values of get parameters are numeric. But the weird thing is that if a value of a get parameter is a string, then the next get parameter is escaped in a wrong way.

For example;

```
echo url_for("konu/index?page=1sort=1")

=>http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/konu?page=1&sort=1
```

but

```
echo url_for("konu/search?query=magnum&page=1&sort=1")
=> http://localhost:8080/frontend_dev.php/konu/search/query/magnum/amp%3Bpage/1/sort/1
```

In second example the ampersand is escaped weirdly. It should be & but it's amp;

I'm using an Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) server and PHP 5.3.3

Is there any solution?

Comment: It looks as if the &page=1 was escaped before being passed to url_for... very strange. Like if you had url_for("konu/search?query=magnum&amp;page=1&sort=1")... try getting an xdebug trace of this function call to see what is going on (or better, do step by step debugging).

Comment: It seems url_for() function is responsible for this behaviour. When I echo the internal uri parameter, I get konu/search?query=magnum&page=1&sort=1 on web page, so I think it's not the PHP server or sth else that makes trouble. It seems the implementation of url_for() function is problematic. There must be a workaround to this but I'm stuck.

Comment: One last detail, the url_for() helper is called inside a template. I think the "double escape" problem is related to calling inside a template. It is escaped once in the template and once in the implementation of url_for(). I'm not sure though :) but still no solution.

Comment: If you want to debug, make sure you use var_dump() and not just echo, var_dump() makes it clearer. I think automatic output escaping is activated in your template (which is a good thing). Read this : http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_page_layout and tell us what settings you have. Are you calling url_for() exactly like in the sample you gave us or are you using intermediate variables?

Comment: The first argument of url_for(which is internal uri) is being passed to template as a parameter, as a string. I will try to pass each http parameter as a seperate argument, all in an array. I think that approach will eliminate my problem since there is not a single & being passed to the template. Thanks for all replies, I'll post the result when I find the chance to try.